# Put a custom string into a file

Tags: c++, string, file

I want to add a new line (string) into the end of an existing file. But it didn't work. Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream input("Sample.ini");
    ofstream output("Sample.ini",ios::app);

    cout << "Lines that have existed in file:" << endl;

    while (input) // Print out the existed line
    {
        string newstring;
        getline(input,newstring);
        cout << newstring << endl;
    }

    cout << "Line you want to add:" << endl;

    string outputstring;
    getline(outputstring,output); // get the whole line of outputstring,
                                  // and deliver it into output file
    return 0;
}
```

The first getline which reads lines inside the file to a string works well. But, the second one, is not.
The compiler returned like this:

> > ...\file test.cpp|35|error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::istream&, std::ofstream&)'|

Answer (score 2):

You wrote too much code. You need two lines only:

```
ofstream output("Sample.ini",ios::app);
output << outputstring;
```

Answer (score -1):

you may want to try `poniter` to file, short & simple

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
 {
  FILE * pFile;
  File = fopen ( "you_file_name.txt" , "a" ); //open the file in append mode
  fputs ( "This is an apple." , pFile );
  fseek ( pFile , 0 , SEEK_END); // 0 means from start & SEEK_END will get you the end of file
  fputs ( "Line you want to add:" , pFile );
  fclose ( pFile );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged C++.